# Error While Restoring Database into SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing this Error in SQL server 2008 R2.
This database was also made in SQL server 2008 R2 so there are no compatibility issues

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server/PC that runs the database server? Second, did you check the option: verify the backup, when doing the backup?

Comment: What is the full error message?  There should be additional information that explains in a little more detail what the failure was related to

Comment: Yes i have tried restarting my PC

Comment: @RazzleDazzle this is everything